# How do I set VS Code to follow Markdown file and section links in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have a Jupyter notebook with the following two Markdown cells. If I open the notebook in a browser using a notebook server, the file links work fine. If I open it in VS Code, only the web link works; the file links do nothing. How do I enable the file links in VS Code?

```
# First Markdown Cell
* [Notebook](test-index.ipynb)
* [Markdown](test.md)
* [Text](test.txt)
* [Cell](#Second-Markdown-Cell)
* [Web](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

```
## Second Markdown Cell
```

Comment: VS Code won't render markdown unless it is a trusted notebook. See the documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_trusted-notebooks

Comment: Thanks, @gofvonx, but that's not the issue. The problem with file links has been fixed in the VSCode Insiders python extension, but the section links still don't work. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1330) for more details.